# Converting a PostGIS grid back to raster

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster

This is a follow-up question (or inverse) of the question
[Converting a PostGIS raster back to vector](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165414).

I am trying to create a workflow that converts a PostGIS raster into a regular grid of polygons, which will be then used to work with vector datasets (e.g. finding distances or even performing map algebra with another vector grid). Hopefully, this will circumvent [the speed issues with PostGIS rasters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126987).

My question is:

After converting a raster `A` to vector using [ST_DumpAsPolygons](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_DumpAsPolygons.html) or [ST_Polygon](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Polygon.html), is there an efficient way to convert the polygon grid back into a raster that is compatible with the original raster `A`?

I know that one can "burn" an individual line or other geometry into a raster as [ST_AsRaster](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_AsRaster.html). But I'm interested in an inverse function of [ST_Polygon](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Polygon.html) that converts a regular polygon grid back to raster form.

Comment: Did you read this? http://geospatialelucubrations.blogspot.com/2014/05/a-guide-to-rasterization-of-vector.html

Comment: @PierreRacine Thanks! I guess what I asked about here is a special case of the linked article. It's probably the simplest special case because the vector to rasterize came from a raster and is already regular.